# To prove the sum is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let$$a_n \ge 0$$ for all $n \in\Bbb N$. Show that if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ converges, then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\sqrt a_n\over n}$$ converges, too.

The hint is to expand $$\left(\sqrt a_n-{1\over n}\right)^2$$

Comment: Isn't the second series upper bounded by the convergent series?

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 9):

Since $$\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n} \le \sqrt{\left(\sum a_n\right) \cdot \sum \left(\frac 1{n^2}\right)} $$

(by Cauchy-Schwarz)

then $\displaystyle \sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ converges since the right hand side does.

Comment: I think you have an unnecessary $^2$

Comment: @DanZimm you're right thanks! Edited ;-)

Answer (score 5):

**Same Hint:** Any square is non-negative. By expanding as suggested, we obtain $0\le \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}\le \frac{1}{2}(a_n+\frac{1}{n^2})$. Now use a Comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Using CS inequality: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n} \leq \sqrt{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n}\cdot \sqrt{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2}}$